# Output of while loop to array?

Tags: php, arrays

I know this is probably some PHP 101 stuff, but I'm here doing PHP 101 and I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem. I have a simple script which produces the Fibonacci sequence to 20 places, but I'd like to return these results into an indexed array and then find the average of those results.

Here's the code:

```
<?php  
    $num = 0;  
    $n1 = 0;  
    $n2 = 1;  
    echo "<h3>Fibonacci series for first 20 numbers: </h3>";  
    echo "\n";  
    echo $n1.' '.$n2.' ';  

    while ($num < 19 ){  
        $n3 = $n2 + $n1;  
        echo $n3.' ';  
        $n1 = $n2;  
        $n2 = $n3;  
        $num = $num + 1;  
    };
?>
```

I hate just asking people to solve my problems for me but given that I'm faaairly new to PHP I'm really not sure how to move forward with this.

Comment: Please state your expected output for question clarity.  I've looked up Fibonacci but others may not bother.

Comment: When you looked around for "how to create an array in PHP" did you not find anything?

Answer (score 2):

Simple code :

```
// ...previous code

$result = array();
while ($num < 19 )  
{  
    $n3 = $n2 + $n1;  
    echo $n3.' ';  
    $n1 = $n2;  
    $n2 = $n3;  
    $num = $num + 1;
    // push to array $result
    $result[]= $n3;
};

echo '<h4>Average : '. array_sum($result) / count($result) .'</h4>';
```

Comment: `$result` is missing the initial values of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
$length = 20;
$fibs   = [0, 1];
for($i=2; $i<$length; $i++)
    $fibs[$i] = $fibs[$i-1] + $fibs[$i-2];

print implode(',', $fibs) . "\n";
printf(
    'The mean average of first %d fibonacci numbers is %f.',
    $length,
    array_sum($fibs)/$length
);
```

Output:

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181
The mean average of first 20 fibonacci numbers is 547.250000.
```

Further we can reduce the for loop to an empty statement. Here's a function that produces an array of items for the Fibonacci sequence:

```
function fibonacci_sequence($length)
{
    for(
        $fibs = [0, 1], $i = 2;
        $i < $length;
        $fibs[$i] = $fibs[$i-1] + $fibs[$i-2], $i++
    );

    return array_slice($fibs, 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is probably overkill for this task, but I thought I'd have a play with it and write a method that doesn't use any arrays.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d4b346b7041f32e727131433714e2caf5b5f7c7))

```
function fibonacci($iterations,$carry=1,$last=0){
    if(--$iterations>1){$carry+=fibonacci($iterations,$carry+$last,$carry);} // control iterations & recurse
    return $carry;                                                           // return the sum
}
$stop=20;
echo fibonacci($stop)/$stop;                                                 // call function
```

Output:

```
547.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of the array_push() function inserts one or more elements to the end of an array.

```
 <pre>

<?php 

$num = 0;  
$n1 = 0;  
$n2 = 1;  
$arr=array();
echo "<h3>Fibonacci series for first 20 numbers: </h3>";  
echo "\n";  
echo $n1.' '.$n2.' ';  
array_push($arr, $n1);
array_push($arr, $n2);
while ($num < 18 )  
{   
    $n3 = $n2 + $n1;  
    array_push($arr, $n3);
    echo $n3.' ';  
    $n1 = $n2;  
    $n2 = $n3;  
    $num = $num + 1; 

};
echo "<br>";

print_r($arr);
$Average= array_sum($arr);
$Average=(int)($Average / count($arr));
echo $Average;

?>

    </pre>
```

Comment: Did you view `$arr`?  It's missing some values isn't it?

Comment: I think he Fibonacci sequence begins with either 0,1 or 1,1.  And yours starts 1,2.

Comment: Your `$arr` is still erroneous.

Comment: Now your `$arr` contains 21 elements.

Comment: Really thank you so much.To pay attention to my answer.I learned more about this.Sorry for carelessness