# depicting php code functions/recursion; grade 11 functions/recursions

Tags: php, recursion

```
function f($n)
{
   if ($n == 0 || $n == 1)
      return 2;
   return  f($n-1) + f($n-2);
}

echo f(5);
```

This gives me `16` but I have no idea why.

I know it goes something like this:

```
return f(4) + f(3)
return f(4) + f(3)+ f(3) + f(1)
```

But now since a value of `n` is `1`, it should return `2`.

So it's essentially

```
return f(4) + f(3)+ f(2)
```

Which should be `9`, but it gives me `16`.

Can anyone explain how please?

Comment: Why would you get `9`? Every final return of the function is `2`, so not sure why you would expect an odd number.

Comment: Because I thought that you add the values, so it was 4 + 3 + 2; can you please expand on how it would be 16?

Comment: f5=f4+f3=f3+f2+f2+f1=f2+f1+f1+f0+f1+f0+2=f1+f0+12=16

Comment: @jh1711 Can you please explain how you got that?

Comment: Lets start the other way around: `f(2) = f(1) + f(0) = 2 + 2 = 4`. Do we agree that f(2) is 4?

Comment: Are we talking _Fibonacci_ here?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542618/2943403  I guess, not exactly.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Fibonacci multiplied by 2. Which explains why every result is even as Sean pointed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f(5) = f(4)                        + f(3)
     = f(3)           + f(2)       + f(2)        + f(1)
     = f(2)     +f(1) + f(1) + f(0) + f(1) + f(0) + 2
     = f(1)+f(0)+ 2   + 2    + 2    + 2    + 2    + 2
     = 2   + 2  + 2   + 2    + 2    + 2    + 2    + 2
     = 16
```

Hope the above interpretation will explain the value 16

Comment: I was working on a similar answer, but like the layout of your answer better

Comment: so the top line, f4 + f3, I get because 5-1=4 and 5-2 =3

but the second: f3 + f2 + f2; how does that work? dont you have to subtract by 2 too? and where did the other f2 come from?

Comment: This is a recursion, so the way you get f4+f3 in line one, in the same way you will get f3 and f2 for f4, and f2 and f1 for f3: as shown in line 2. And so on. Follow the code in my answer in this manner and you get get a better picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
f(0)=2
f(1)=2
f(2)=f(1)+f(0)=2+2=4
f(3)=f(2)+f(1)=4+2=6
f(4)=f(3)+f(2)=6+4=10
f(5)=f(4)+f(3)=10+6=16
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a visual representation of the recursive function, showing the return on each iteration

```
                      f(5)                          1st
                    /       \
                   /         \
                  /           \
                 /             \
                /               \
               /                 \
            f(4)       +        f(3)                2nd
          /     \               /  \
         /       \             /    \
      f(3)  +   f(2)   +    f(2)  +f(1)             3rd
      /  \      /  \        /  \     |
   f(2)+f(1)+f(1)+f(0) + f(1)+f(0)+  2              4th
   /  \   |    | +  |      |    |    |
f(1)+f(0)+2 +  2 +  2  +   2 +  2 +  2              5th
  |    |  |    |    |      |    |    |
  2 +  2 +2 +  2 +  2  +   2 +  2 +  2 = 16        Result
```

Comment: Good one; vertical representation is nice and clean. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more easy to read break-down of the calculations:

```
f(5 - 1) + f(5 - 2)

(f(4 - 1) + f(4 - 2)) + (f(3 - 1) + f(3 - 2))

((f(3 - 1) + f(3 - 2)) + (f(2 - 1) + f(2 - 2))) + ((f(2 - 1) + f(2 - 2)) + 2)

Above simplifies to:
((f(2) + 2) + (2 + 2)) + ((2 + 2) + 2)

Then to:
((f(2) + 2) + 4) + (6)

Then remove extra parenthesis:
f(2) + 2 + 4 + 6

Then simplify:
f(2) + 12

Continuing:
f(2 - 1) + f(2 - 2) + 12

Simplify:
2 + 2 + 12 = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time your recursive function is called and passed a value greater than `1`, you get a "fork" (or a subsequent recursion call).

Condensed syntax: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1Ob4A))

```
function f($n){
  return $n<2 ? 2 : f($n-1)+f($n-2);
}
```

When `f(1)`, there is no fork.  return `2`

When `f(2)`, there is only 1 fork.  return `4`  (LHS=2 RHS=2)

When `f(3)`, after an initial fork, there is a subsequent fork @ LHS branch.  return `6`  (LHS=4 RHS=2)

When `f(4)`, after an initial fork, there are 3 forks: 2xLHS & 1xRHS.  return `10`  (LHS=6 RHS=4)

When `f(5)`, after an initial fork, there are 6 forks: 4xLHS & 2x$RHS.  return `16`  (LHS=10 RHS=6)